# Relationship "finite mean" <-> "absolutely integrable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the relationship between the property of a random variable (i.e. a measurable function defined on some probability space) being absolutely integrable, i.e. $$\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$$and having finite mean, i.e.$$\mathbb{E}X<\infty\quad ?$$Obviously the first implies the second, but does the converse hold too ?

Comment: Exact equivalence, since E(X) is only defined when E(|X|) is finite.

Comment: @Did Could you maybe make an answer out of that ? Why doesn't it make sense to define E(X) as long as this quantity is finite ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exact equivalence, since E(X) is only defined when E(|X|) is finite. In Lebesgue theory of integration, the integral of a real-valued measurable function $f$ exists if and only if $|f|$ has finite integral.

Answer (score 0):

The Lebesgue integral is well-defined if $f^+:=\max(f,0)$ or $f^-:=\min(f,0)$ is integrable, because then you can set $\int f =\int f^+ -\int f^-$.

Hence one could make the trivial counterexample $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{F}:=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mathbb{P}:=\lambda$ (Lebesgue measure) and $X(t):=-1$. The positive part is zero and therefore the integral is well defined, but $\mathbb{E}[X]=-\infty<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\infty$.