# Does mean zero imply integrability?

Tags: probability

Does $E[X]=0$ imply $X$ is integrable i.e. $E[|X|]<\infty$?

I feel like this (or similar question) has been asked before / solution is simple but couldn't find it / figure it out.

Comment: The answer is basically explained in this question's accepted answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984004/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E(X)=0$ implies that $E(X)$ is finite, i.e. $E(X^+)-E(X^-)$ is finite, hence $E(X^+)$ and $E(X^-)$ are individually finite (otherwise we cannot write $E(X)=0$) which implies that $E(X^+)+E(X^-)$ is finite, being sum of two finite quantities. But $E|X|=E(X^+)+E(X^-)$ which is thus finite.